# different animation frame stacks for only 1 class in Flash cs4

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

is it possible to reuse a class i have created but have it render different animation frames? currently i have a Fish symbol which is pointed to a fish class, the Fish symbol timeline layer 1 has a set of animation frame of a fish, is it possible to add another type of fish animation frame into this symbol such that when instantiating this fish class i will be able to "call" or "play" this "other" fish animation frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose fish movie clip has animation 1 from frame 1 to 8 and animation 2 from frame 9 to 15.

```
// to run animation 1
fishMC.gotoAndPlay(1);

// to run animation 2
fishMC.gotoAndPlay(9)
```

You need to place `stop()` on frame 8 and 15.